# Show image in Xcode based on Firestore boolean value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to coding and could really use your help!
I am trying to show a 'bestseller' image on a product based on a boolean.
I am using Firestore for the database.
I have managed to get the value of the 'bestseller' field on all the documents, but I don't know what to do next.
This is my code so far. This shows the bestsellerImg on all of the products - instead of only the ones where the value = "True"

Here are two pictures to show what i mean :)

[image]

[image]

the swift file/class "ProductsVC" is controlling the ViewController with the collectionView in it.

Code from "ProductsVC"

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ProductsVC: UIViewController, ProductCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryName: UILabel!
    
    var products = [Product]()
    var category: Category!
    var db : Firestore!
    var listener : ListenerRegistration!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: Identifiers.ProductCell, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ProductCell)
        setQuery()
        categoryName.text = category.name

    }
    

    
    func setQuery() {
        
        var ref: Query!
        ref = db.products(category: category.id)
        listener = ref.addSnapshotListener({ (snap, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            snap?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
                let data = change.document.data()
                let product = Product.init(data: data)
                
                switch change.type {
                case .added:
                    self.onDocumentAdded(change: change, product: product)
                case .modified:
                    self.onDocumentModified(change: change, product: product)
                case .removed:
                    self.onDoucmentRemoved(change: change)
                
                }
            })
        })
    }
    
    
    
    func productAddToCart(product: Product) {
        if UserService.isGuest {
            self.simpleAlert(title: "Hej!", msg: "Man kan kun tilføje ting til sin kurv hvis man er oprettet som Fender-bruger. ")
            return
        }
        
        PaymentCart.addItemToCart(item: product)
        self.addedtocart(title: "Tilføjet til kurv!", msg: "")
    }
 
}

extension ProductsVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func onDocumentAdded(change: DocumentChange, product: Product) {
        let newIndex = Int(change.newIndex)
        products.insert(product, at: newIndex)
        collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: newIndex, section: 0)])
    }
    
    func onDocumentModified(change: DocumentChange, product: Product) {
        if change.oldIndex == change.newIndex {
            let index = Int(change.newIndex)
            products[index] = product
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
        } else {
            let oldIndex = Int(change.oldIndex)
            let newIndex = Int(change.newIndex)
            products.remove(at: oldIndex)
            products.insert(product, at: newIndex)
            
            collectionView.moveItem(at: IndexPath(item: oldIndex, section: 0), to: IndexPath(item: newIndex, section: 0))
            
        }
    }
    
    func onDoucmentRemoved(change: DocumentChange) {
        let oldIndex = Int(change.oldIndex)
        products.remove(at: oldIndex)
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: oldIndex, section: 0)])
        
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        products.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ProductCell, for: indexPath) as? ProductCell {
            
            cell.configureCell(product: products[indexPath.item], delegate: self)
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailProductVC()
        let selectedProduct = products[indexPath.item]
        vc.product = selectedProduct
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = view.frame.width
        let cellWidth = (width - 30) / 3
        let cellHeight = cellWidth * 2.1

        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

My struct

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Product {
    var name: String
    var id: String
    var category: String
    var price: Double
    var productDescription: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var timeStamp: Timestamp
    var inStore: Int
    var bestseller: Bool
    var quantity: Int
    
    init(
        name: String,
        id: String,
        category: String,
        price: Double,
        productDescription: String,
        imageUrl: String,
        timeStamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(),
        inStore: Int,
        bestseller: Bool,
        quantity: Int) {
        
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.category = category
        self.price = price
        self.productDescription = productDescription
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.timeStamp = timeStamp
        self.inStore = inStore
        self.bestseller = bestseller
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
        init(data: [String: Any]) {
            name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
            category = data["category"] as? String ?? ""
            price = data["price"] as? Double ?? 0.0
            productDescription = data["productDescription"] as? String ?? ""
            imageUrl = data["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
            timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
            inStore = data["inStore"] as? Int ?? 0
            bestseller = data["bestseller"] as? Bool ?? true
            quantity = data["quantity"] as? Int ?? 0
        }
        
        static func modelToData(product: Product) -> [String: Any] {
            
            let data : [String: Any] = [
                "name" : product.name,
                "id" : product.id,
                "category" : product.category,
                "price" : product.price,
                "productDescription" : product.productDescription,
                "imageUrl" : product.imageUrl,
                "timeStamp" : product.timeStamp,
                "inStore" : product.inStore,
                "bestseller" : product.bestseller,
                "quantity" : product.quantity
            ]
            
            return data
        }
    }

extension Product : Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Code from "ProductCell"

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import Firebase

protocol ProductCellDelegate : class {
    func productAddToCart(product: Product)
}

class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bestsellerImg: UIImageView!
    
    var db: Firestore?
    
    
    
    weak var delegate : ProductCellDelegate?
    private var product: Product!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        getInStore()
       }
    

    
    func getInStore() {
                Firestore.firestore().collection("products").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                    var isBestseller = document.get("bestseller")
                    
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    
    
    func configureCell(product: Product, delegate: ProductCellDelegate) {
        self.product = product
        self.delegate = delegate
        
        titleLbl.text = product.name
        
        if let url = URL(string: product.imageUrl) {
            let placeholder = UIImage(named: "Fender")
            imgView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            let options : KingfisherOptionsInfo =
                [KingfisherOptionsInfoItem.transition(.fade(0.1))]
            imgView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: placeholder, options: options)
        }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.currencyCode = "DKK"
        if let price = formatter.string(from: product.price as NSNumber) {
        priceLbl.text = price
        
        
        }
}
    
    @IBAction func addToCart(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.productAddToCart(product: product)

            
    }
    

    }
```

Comment: Your code logic looks good, what is the wrong behavior?

Comment: Your code is a bit iffy. You're getting all of the documents within the products collection - could be 1 or 100. Then you're iterating over each document one at a time and setting the same class variable `self.bestsellerImg` over and over. I suppose if you want the image to flicker, that would do it but I would guess that's not the intention.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for taking your time to answer :) 
What should i do then? I've tried for days without knowing what to do..

Comment: @luca_999 It shows the bestsellerImg on all the products instead of only showing the ones who have the value "true". 
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Can you clarify what your attempting to do? If there are 5 documents and they have their `bestseller` property set to true, true, false, false, false then the `self.bestsellerImg.` will be set to true then to true again, and then false and false and false. So what's the purpose of that? Is there more data stored in each document? Is this going to be a list of books or something along those lines? Keep in mind that we only know what you share with us so the purpose of the code needs to be very clear if you would like assistance with it.

Comment: Hey @Jay I have edited the post now. Hopefully you know what i mean. There are two pictures showing it. Thank you!

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do.  If there are 100 documents, you're updating the same var over and over for each document. e.g. If you're trying to add 'bestseller' to different images, that code won't do it because the same var is being updated, not each images var. Does that make sense? oh btw, please don't include links in questions - they can break and if that happens, future readers won't know what they were. Include the images in the actual question.

Comment: @Jay Ahhhh.. I get it. I don't know if I have the solution haha, but I can see what you mean. 
But do you get what I'm trying to do ?
Basically there is a lot of products in the shop. I want to show the the "bestseller" image on the products that have the "bestseller" field = true in firestore. I hope it makes sense. I'm sorry that things are unclear.

Comment: I get what you're generally trying to do; the confusing part is how you're attempting to go about it - we don't know how the UI is set up. Is this a tableView with a list of books? If so where do you load each book? Wouldn't the bestseller node be part of that data? How are you populating the tableView dataSource? Those are the important parts that should be in your question with a [minimal amount of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jay I have updated the post once again with new information. I can't post pictures - only links because I'm a new user. Thanks :)

Comment: I removed the links and added the two relevant image for you. Again though - there's not enough code in the question to really be of help. How are you populating the dataSource? The code in the question is completely unrelated to what you're trying to do so it's important we understand how you want it to relate. In other words, the code in your question reads a bunch of documents from Firebase and updates the same var over and over. That will have no effect on your tableView of the images contained within.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for editing! :) I have updated the post again. I hope this is what you mean. Thank you for being so patient!

Comment: Again, how is your datasource populated? The code in `getInStore` reads the products collection but there's no correlation between that code and the products dataSource (I  assume that's an array) and no correlation to what's being displayed in your tableView.

Comment: @Jay Updated. Thanks

Comment: A bit too much code and I am not sure what/where the issue is. Let me walk through it: The tableView datasource is populated in setQuery let product = Product.init(data: data). Each product knows if it's a best seller because it has a best seller property which is either true or false. So when the products are loaded, that property is set. So as your tableView delegate is creating each cell cell.configureCell(product: products[indexPath.item]why don't you just have a piece of code in ProductCell that says if self.isBestSeller then use the bestSeller image, else use the regular image?

Comment: @Jay It worked! Thank you so so much for your time and help:)) I really appreciate it! :) Also thank you for guiding me on how to make a question more precise!

Comment: @MayaBoelsmand: I would really recommend looking into separating your business logic from the view. Each CollectionViewCell talks to your database and that will make the app really slow really fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, there may be a pretty simple solution that would simplify what you're trying to do.

Let me walk through it and then make a suggestion:

The tableView datasource is populated in the setQuery function with

```
func setQuery() { 
  ...
  snap?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
     let data = change.document.data()
     let product = Product.init(data: data)
```

Each product knows if it's a best seller because it has a best seller property which is either true or false. So when the products are loaded from firebase, that property is set with the Product.init.

As your tableView delegate is creating each cell

```
cell.configureCell(product: products[indexPath.item]
```

why don't you just have a piece of code in ProductCell that says if the product is a bestSeller then use the bestSeller image, else use the regular image?

```
func configureCell(product: Product, delegate: ProductCellDelegate) {
   self.product = product
   self.delegate = delegate
   
   if self.product.bestSeller == true {
      //set the image the bestseller image
   } else {
      //set the image to the regular image
   }
```